# dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a dropdownlist which is leavetype in this sickleave,urgent leave types when I select urgent leave in database value goes to sick leave i.e. in database

```
leasid leavedescription leavetypeid:
1      abcdefe          1
```

where as I select 2 in form

where is the error?

this is the code

```
cc.leavee(Txt_leaveValue,  Convert.ToInt32(leavedrop.SelectedValue));
```

and

```
LMS.leavetype le = new LMS.leavetype();
        DropDownList2.DataSource = le.getdep();
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "leaveID";
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "leavetypeID";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you checking for IsPostBack in your Page_Load() event?

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // init dropdown here
    DMSLIB.leavetype le = new DMSLIB.leavetype();
    DropDownList2.DataSource = le.getdep();
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "leaveID";
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "leavetypeID";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```

If you forget that test, you're re-initializing it before reading the value.